# Making an Array with range specified

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function called addToArray. This function should:
take two arguments, num1 and num2
use a for loop to add each number from num1 to num2 to an array

so if num1 = 2 and num2 = 4
then array = [2,3,4]

my attempt:

```
addToArray = function (num1, num2) {

for (var i = num1; i < num2 + 1 ; i++) {
array.push(i);
}

return array;
}
```

Comment: Cool. So what's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not initialize the `array` and `addToArray` variables, which will cause JS to crash.

```
var addToArray = function (num1, num2) {
  var array = [];

  for (var i = num1; i <= num2 ; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }

  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addToArray(num1, num2) {
  var array = []; //missing initialization
  for (var i = num1; i <= num2; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one line before the for loop

```
var array=[];    //initialize the variable
```

So completely

```
addToArray = function (num1, num2) {
    var array=[];
    for (var i = num1; i < num2 + 1 ; i++) {
        array.push(i);
    } 
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in ES 6 :

```
var addToArray =  (num1, num2) => {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = num1; i < num2 + 1 ; i++)  array.push(i);
  return array;
}
console.log(addToArray(2,5)); // [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```